# SVN moving the Repository physical folder from one drive to another drive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Need help in moving the Repository data folder from one network share drive to another drive as mentioned below

Repositories URL, http://servername/svn and it contains Repo1, Repo2, Repo3

Repositories Root (data folder):
\Network1\RootFolder1\Folder1\

File explorer:
\Network1\RootFolder1\Folder1\Repo1
\Network1\RootFolder1\Folder1\Repo2
\Network1\RootFolder1\Folder1\Repo3

I want to move the Repositories to another Network share as shown below but without changing the base Repository URL. Just want to move the physical folder location of the repositories to another path.
\Network2\Root\Repo1
\Network2\Root\Repo2
\Network2\Root\Repo3

I am expecting no changes to the client the way they are connected to the svn.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you get on the browser is configured in the apache configuration. So you can easily move around the actual repository data from one network shared drive to another freely.

Let me show you by example.
Say physical repositories are stored at the location as follows:

```
Repo-1: /Network/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo1
Repo-2: /Network/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo2
Repo-3: /Network/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo3
```

Access to these repositories with URL as follows:

```
Repo-1: http://url/svn/Repo-1
Repo-2: http://url/svn/Repo-2
Repo-3: http://url/svn/Repo-3
```

This is how it looks in apache configuration file:

```
<Location /svn> 
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /Network/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Some Name"
AuthUserFile /some/path/userfile
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Now when you move the repository to the new location that is the following locaiton:

```
Repo-1: /Network-2/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo1
Repo-2: /Network-2/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo2
Repo-3: /Network-2/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos/Repo3
```

all you need to do is change the `SVNParentPath` and you are all set to go with the same url.

Your new apache configuration file will look as follows:

```
<Location /svn> 
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /Network-2/Data/Folder/Folder/svn/repos
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Some Name"
AuthUserFile /some/path/userfile
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Hope this helps.